# How to delete tensorflow-datasets data

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, delete-file, tensorflow-datasets

I downloaded The Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset using [tensorflow-datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) and it contains corrupt data:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 240 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
```

I want to delete this data so that I can re-download to try avoid the corruption.

Is there a way I can do this using the library?

If not, where can I find the data in my file directory? I have located the tensorflow-datasets dir ([thanks to the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview#tfdsload_a_dataset_in_one_line)) in AppData/~/python/~/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow_datasets but I cannot find the dataset. The size of the folder is 10MB so maybe it is saved somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the datasets are stored in a .keras folder under your home folder. Simply deleting the old dataset will cause it to redownload upon execution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting the dataset, you can try following things..

1. Change the directory to download the dataset using `data_dir` parameter.
2. Use `download=False` parameter while loading the dataset, which will not download the dataset and will always use the online version.

Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load) for usage of the parameters.

Comment: Are you sure it uses the online version? In the documentation, it says this:
```download bool (optional), whether to call tfds.core.DatasetBuilder.download_and_prepare before calling tfds.core.DatasetBuilder.as_dataset. If False, data is expected to be in data_dir. If True and the data is already in data_dir, when data_dir is a Placer path.```